# Suppose $F,G$ are a partitions on $A$,$B$ and $A \cap B=\emptyset$. Prove that $F\cup G$ is a partition of $A \cup B$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $F,G$ are a partitions on  $A$,$B$ and $A \cap B=\emptyset$
>   Prove that $F\cup G$ is a partition of $A \cup B$.

My attempt:

To prove that $F \cup G$ is a partition on $A \cup B$, we need to show that:

1. $\bigcup \bigl(F \cup G \bigr) = A \cup B$
2. $\bigcup \bigl(F \cup G \bigr)$ is pairwise disjoint
3. $\forall X \in \bigcup \bigl(F \cup G \bigr) ( X ≠ \emptyset)$

1.

$(\rightarrow)$

Take $x \in \bigcup F \cup G$. Then exists some $X \in F$ or $X \in G$, such that $x \in X$.

If $X \in F$, then $x \in A$.

If $X \in G$, then $x \in B$.

It follows that $x \in A \cup B$, which means that $\bigcup F \cup G \subseteq A \cup B$.

$(\leftarrow)$

Take $x \in A \cup B$.

It follows that $x \in A$ or $x \in B$

If $x \in A$ then exists some $X \in F$ such that $x \in X$. And that means that $x \in \bigcup F$.

If $x \in B$ then exists some $X \in G$ such that $x \in X$. And that means that $x \in \bigcup G$.

Hence $x \in \bigcup F \cup G$

Since arbitrary element was considered, we have $A \cup B \subseteq \bigcup F \cup G $

Both directions were shown, thus we have our result $\bigcup F \cup G = A \cup B$

2.

Take arbitrary $X,Y \in F \cup G$

If $X,Y \in F $ then $X \cap Y = \emptyset$, because $F$ is a partition on $A$

If $X,Y \in G $ then $X \cap Y = \emptyset$, because $G$ is a partition on $B$

Suppose $X \in F$ and $Y \in G$

Take arbitrary $x \in X$. We know that $x \in A$, and $A \cap B = \emptyset$, hence $x \notin B$ and $x \notin Y$. Hence not a single element of the set $X$ is in $Y$, which means that $X \cap Y = \emptyset$

By the same reasoning, we can show that if $Y \in F$ and $X \in G$, we still have $X \cap Y = \emptyset$.

Since $X,Y$ were arbitrary, we conclude that $F \cup G$ is pairwise disjoint.

3.

Since $F$ is a partition on $A$, $\emptyset \notin F$

Since $G$ is a partition on $B$, $\emptyset \notin G$

Hence $\emptyset \notin F \cup G$.

We've shown that three properites hold, hence $F \cup G$ is a partition on $A \cup B$. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. Maybe it's just me but once you're comfortable with proofs, you don't need to tediously write every step. That is, your proof could be written as:

1. Every set in $F\cup G$ is nonempty: obvious.
2. $F\cup G$ is disjoint: there's only the case where $X\in F$ and $Y\in G$ (the other cases are obvious). If $X$ and $Y$ are not disjoint, then there is some $x\in X\cap Y$. Then $x\in A\cap B$, contradicting that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.
3. We have that $\bigcup(F\cup G)=\bigcup F\cup\bigcup G=A\cup B$.